# Can I make Visual Studio create the Debug DLL as XXXd.DLL instead of XXX.DLL?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, debugging, release

I have found a solution for this, but it only works if you use .DEF files (I don't).

I wonder if this can be done without .DEF files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Project > Properties`. Then `Configuration Properties > Linker > General > Output file`. Here you should have something like: `$(OutDir)\$(ProjectName).dll` just put `$(OutDir)\$(ProjectName)d.dll`

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Visual Studio, you can set the output file path through the project's property pages:

`Properties --> Linker --> General --> Output File`